# Android Play Store Subscription Billing doesn't trigger any action

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have successfully implemented the in-app purchase flow, now I am trying to switch to the subscription model but something is wrong in the makePurchase() method, it doesn't open the window for the user to make the payment.

```
private void createPurchaseFlow(String productID, PostTaskListener<String> callback)
{
    Print.e("createPurchaseFlow productID: "+ productID);
    PurchasesUpdatedListener purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult,
                                       List<Purchase> purchases)
        {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
                    && purchases != null)
            {
                for (Purchase purchase : purchases)
                {
                    consumePurchase(purchase,productID,callback);
                }
            }
            else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==
                    BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED)
            {
                callback.onPostTask("User Canceled");
                Print.e("onPurchasesUpdated: Purchase Canceled");
            }
            else
            {
                callback.onPostTask("Purchase Failed");
                Print.e("onPurchasesUpdated: Error");
            }
        }
    };

    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(activity)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build();

    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult)
        {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==
                    BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
            {
                Print.e("OnBillingSetupFinish connected");
                queryProduct(productID,callback);
            }
            else
            {
                Print.e("OnBillingSetupFinish failed");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected()
        {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            Print.e("onBillingServiceDisconnected");
            callback.onPostTask("Billing Service Disconnected");
        }
    });
}

private void queryProduct(String subscriptionID, PostTaskListener<String> callback)
{
    QueryProductDetailsParams queryProductDetailsParams =
            QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    .setProductList(
                            ImmutableList.from(
                                    QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                            .setProductId(subscriptionID)
                                            .setProductType(
                                                    BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                                            .build()))
                    .build();

    billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
            queryProductDetailsParams,
            new ProductDetailsResponseListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onProductDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult,
                                                     @NonNull List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList)
                {
                    if (!productDetailsList.isEmpty())
                    {
                        Print.e("onProductDetailsResponse");
                        ProductDetails productDetails = productDetailsList.get(0);
                        makePurchase(productDetails);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        callback.onPostTask(null);
                        Print.e("onProductDetailsResponse: No subscriptions");
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}

private void makePurchase(ProductDetails productDetails)
{
    Print.e("makePurchase: " + productDetails.getName());

    List<BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams> productDetailsParamsList = ImmutableList.from(
            BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    .setProductDetails(productDetails)
                    .build()
    );

    BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams =
            BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setProductDetailsParamsList(productDetailsParamsList)
                    .build();

    BillingResult billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams);


    Print.e("billingResult: " + billingResult.getResponseCode() +
            " getDebugMessage: " +  billingResult.getDebugMessage() +
            " toString: " +  billingResult.toString());
}
```

It doesn't print the messages after this line

```
BillingResult billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams);
```

so I placed breakpoints and the code run until this code:

```
        List<BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams> productDetailsParamsList = ImmutableList.from(
            BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    .setProductDetails(productDetails)
                    .build()
    );
```

and then nothing happens, no errors, zero logs. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I needed to make this change:

```
List<BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams> productDetailsParamsList = ImmutableList.from(
            BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    .setOfferToken(productDetails.getSubscriptionOfferDetails().get(0).getOfferToken())
                    .setProductDetails(productDetails)
                    .build()
    );
```

I added this line:

```
 .setOfferToken(productDetails.getSubscriptionOfferDetails().get(0).getOfferToken())
```

Comment: You needed to make what change? Please expand on the answer so that it is helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who's running into this issue: The OP had the right idea, but didn't really explain it - and their solution doesn't help if you don't have an offer on your subscription.

The root issue seems to be that `BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.Builder` actually *hangs* if you don't supply an `offerToken` for a subscription. This is pretty egregious, IMHO, but fortunately it's also pretty easy to get around:

```
val productBuilder = BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
    .setProductDetails(productDetails)
    .setOfferToken(token)
```

...where `token` is a `String` that's set to a real offer token from `BillingClient` (using code like the OP's) if you have one, or **an empty string (`""`) if you don't**.

The important bit being that you *must* call `setOfferToken()` with a (non-null) value, or the `Builder` will hang.

[The official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.Builder#setOfferToken(java.lang.String)) say "Calling this method is not needed for One-time products", which *could* be taken to mean that it **is** needed for subscription products - but that's not explicitly stated. Like I said, a pretty egregious fail in API design (and documentation).